# Cast from unsigned long long to double and vice versa changes the value

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

When writing a C++ code I suddenly realised that my numbers are incorrectly casted from `double` to `unsigned long long`.

To be specific, I use the following code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned long long ull = numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();
  double d = static_cast<double>(ull);
  unsigned long long ull2 = static_cast<unsigned long long>(d);
  cout << ull << endl << d << endl << ull2 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Ideone live example](http://ideone.com/B4V5St).

When this code is executed on my computer, I have the following output:

```
18446744073709551615
1.84467e+019
9223372036854775808
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I expected the first and third numbers to be exactly the same (just like on Ideone) because I was sure that `long double` took 10 bytes, and stored the mantissa in 8 of them. I would understand if the third number were truncated compared to first one - just for the case I'm wrong with the floating-point numbers format. But here the values are twice different!

So, the main question is: why? And how can I predict such situations?

Some details: I use Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7, compile for x86, and `sizeof(long double) == 8` for my system.

Comment: The problem does not occur in your ideone live example, so perhaps this is a bug in MSVC

Comment: So you are saying you get a different result on your home computer to the IDE one version?

Comment: In MSVC do you still get the problem with `numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - 100` ?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the sign bit.  Multiply your last result by 2.

Comment: @TimB, yes, result on my computer are not expected.

Comment: @M.M, for `numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - 100` it still reports  `9223372036854775808` (this is `1 << 63`, as far as I understand)

Comment: this might be conforming behaviour because the int is not exactly representible in the double

Comment: @M.M, the value of double is `1.84467e+019` - it obviously shouldn't be converted to `unsigned long long` as `1<<63`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, not sure I understood your comment. Yes, the result is `1 << 63` while expected is `1 << 64 - 1`, but this result is reported for many numbers close to `1 << 64`

Comment: I'm suspicious about the signed bit here. Is there any chance it got converted to a signed integer then from that to unsigned? A /2 error suggests 1 bit missing.

Comment: @M.M, because there's a closer value in `unsigned long long` type

Comment: @TimB, looks like an interesting idea. Is this stated anywhere in standard?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Not that I'm aware of, why I posted it as a comment not an answer :)

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: could you try with 0xf000000000000000 to see if you MSVC 2013 is concerned with what I suspect to be a bug?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, my MSVC 2013 outputs `0xf000000000000000` correctly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`18446744073709551615` is not exactly representible in `double` (in IEEE754). This is not unexpected, as a 64-bit floating point obviously cannot represent all integers that are representible in 64 bits.

According to the C++ Standard, it is *implementation-defined* whether the next-highest or next-lowest `double` value is used. Apparently on your system, it selects the next highest value, which seems to be `1.8446744073709552e19`.  You could confirm this by outputting the double with more digits of precision.

Note that this is larger than the original number.

When you convert this double to integer, the behaviour is covered by [conv.fpint]/1:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The **behavior is undefined** if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

So this code potentially causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). When undefined behaviour has occurred, anything can happen, including (but not limited to) bogus output.

---

The question was originally posted with `long double`, rather than `double`. On my gcc, the `long double` case behaves correctly, but on OP's MSVC it gave the same error.  This could be explained by gcc using 80-bit `long double`, but MSVC using 64-bit `long double`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is surprisingly simple. This is what is happening in *your* case:

`18446744073709551615` when converted to a `double` is round **up** to the nearest number that the floating point can represent. (The closest representable number is larger).

When that's converted back to an `unsigned long long`, it's larger than `max()`. Formally, the behaviour of converting this back to an `unsigned long long` is *undefined* but what appears to be happening in your case is a wrap around.

The observed significantly smaller number is the result of this.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the rounding differs on the IDEOne example? Or why it happens on max()-100

Comment: If it wrapped around mod 2^64 you'd get a number near 0.

Comment: @TimB, as far as I understand, in IdeOne `sizeof(long double)` is `12` while on my computer it's `8`.

Comment: @TimB, (i) IDEOne example was originally using a long double, (ii) floating point details could differ are two possibilities. a 12 byte double with appropriate mantissa / exponent split *could* represent `max()` exactly.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I think you're wrong because `1ULL << 64 == 0`, not `1ULL << 64 == 1 ULL << 63`

Comment: 1ULL << 64 = one cat eaten due to UB. Start with the obvious. The compiler is **not** broken.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I think this answer is correct, except for the part about wrapping around. The conversion to integer is undefined behavior if it won't fit.

Comment: @Bathsheba Then explain how wrapping 2^64 modulo 2^64 gives you 2^63. The standard does say it's undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to `double` approximation to `long long`. Its precision means ~100 units error at 10^19; as you try to convert values around the upper limit of long long range, it overflows. Try to convert 10000 lower value instead :)

BTW, at Cygwin, the third printed value is zero

Comment: Yes, here should be the overflow, but I didn't think it's UB - I was sure that on all reasonable platforms the upper bits are just truncated. You're right, when I use `numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max() - 10000`, it works.

Comment: One should never rely on it! Note, for example, that it may be a hardware built-in operation.