# Round long double to unsigned long long in c++

Tags: c++

Is there any built-in function in C++ to convert `long double` into `unsigned long long`?


 As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33825360/11122122), it looks like `double` is not sufficient to represent some `unsigned long long` values. Correct me if `long double` is also not enough.


 I also know that there's a function called, `roundl` that rounds a `long double` but returns a `long double` again.

 Another function `lround` can only return `long` and works on a smaller range of values.


 So given a `long double`, how to do I round it to the nearest integer of type, `unsigned long long`?

 Thanks.

**Related Question**

 [Cast from unsigned long long to double and vice versa changes the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33824954/11122122)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast from unsigned long long to double and vice versa changes the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824954/cast-from-unsigned-long-long-to-double-and-vice-versa-changes-the-value)

Comment: Can't you use `llroundl`?

Comment: What result do you want if the value, rounded to the nearest integer, is not representable in the `unsigned long long` type?

Comment: @Abstract, thanks for pointing that out. I have read that question before posting this one. However, I always feel uncomfortable rounding to `long double` and static_cast that into integer.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yes! I didn't know this function. I guess it's safe that I use `llroundl` and then static_cast the result into `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** use `std::llroundl`, assuming the initial value is smaller than `2^64`. If it is bigger, then it wouldn't fit anyway, so up to you to decide what to do with it.

IEEE 754 floating point numbers can represent any integer up to a certain point. If you convert an integer to such a number, and then back to the same integral type, you'll get the exact same value back as long as the integer is not larger than the representable limit.

For double precision numbers, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/71141), that's `2^53`, which is big enough for all 32 bit integers. We can apply the same general formula for for quad precision numbers, and get `2^113`, which is big enough for all 64 bit integers.

So, if `long double` on your implementation is a quad precision number, and `unsigned long long` is a 64 bit integer, then you can safely do the roundtrip:

```
unsigned long long i = /* a very big value */;
long double d = i; // safe because it's a widening conversion
assert(static_cast<unsigned long long>(d) == i); // should pass
```

Now, if you don't have an integer in that `long double`, then of course there'll be some loss, because that fraction will have to be cut. If you round the number first, you'll end up with an integer, and that is representable, so no loss (assuming it's not bigger than `2^113`), but of course you'll still end up with a different number than the one you started with before the rounding.

```
long double d = /* a very big value */;
unsigned long long i = static_cast<unsigned long long>(std::roundl(d));
```

Or you can avoid the cast altogether by using `std::llroundl`:

```
long double d = /* a very big value */;
unsigned long long i = std::llroundl(d);
```

Although you'll need to be careful about negative numbers (but that's easy to check beforehand).

All of this assumes that your `long double` is never bigger than `2^64`, but if it were, then you wouldn't be able to fit it into the `unsigned long long` anyway.

Comment: The disclaimer _"All of this assumes that your long double is never bigger than 2^64, but if it were, then you wouldn't be able to fit it into the unsigned long long anyway."_ is what I focused the most on in my answer, but I dropped the ball. +1